# Huge site scrape/crawl with GAS: Error - Argument too large:value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've done a scraping script that scrapes any site's (url to be entered) inner pages one by one through crawling, fetching other inner url and processing them to fetch all the pages and extract their pure text (stripped html). See [my previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648235/google-apps-scraping-script-to-run-regullary-till-all-sites-inner-pages-are-ext) answer. The script works well, and I manage to stop it automatically when its run time is close to certain limit and I also re-start it through time trigger to continue scrape execution.

As some persistent data I use *ScriptCache* and *ScriptProperties* (for little value variables).

- I save *not-yet-processed* links and *processed* links in ScriptCache right before I stop script upon time limit. For this I `join()` array of links into string variable: `scriptCache.put('processed_urls', processed_urls.join(','))`
- I retrieve *not-yet-processed* links and *processed* links from ScriptCache when I re-start script for a following run. Here I rather `split()` cached string into array:  `processed_urls = scriptCache.get('processed_urls').split(',')`

The problem that links might be SO big in number that script fails, indicating that value is too big. 
Error details (from an automatic email):

```
Start      Function     Error Message                Trigger            End
4/20/15 
12:57 PM    scrape   Argument too large:value 
                     (line 139, file "Code")        time-based    4/20/15 12:57PM
```

this line: `joined_links = links.join(',');`

> Argument too large:  value (line 139, file "Code")

since the number of site links is huge, to turn array into string for the following string is of bid value... This happens when the string value is really over 25K.

**What might be a way out?**

**Also, when the google doc is too large, where i put the scraped text, it's slow for interacting with...?**

Answer (score 0):

Script cache (and properties) have a limit that you reached. Instead store your pending links list as spreadsheet rows (or even a single cell). You can also spread your data in more cache entries but there is also a total that you could reach. To spread it easily just name your cached values "c1" "c2" etc until you dont find any more.

Comment: GAS Cache stores up to [100Kb](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#put(String,String)) value. The problem is not in properties storing, but in **GAS string variable limited to certain value**: `joined_links = links.join(',')` or `scriptCache.put('links', links.join(','))`